# Recyclerview Deleting the animation of a previously selected item

Tags: android, algorithm, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I animate the recyclerview's selected item and I want the animation from the previous item to be deleted when another item is selected

[image: recyclerview snapscroll horizontal]

my codes are as follows;

MainActivity codes;

```
val premiumRecyclerAdapter: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerPremium)


        premiumRecyclerAdapter.layoutManager =
            object : LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) {
                override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
                    return false
                }

            }

        premiumRecyclerAdapter.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        premiumRecyclerAdapter.adapter = ProfilePremiumRecyclerAdapter(getPremium(), premiumRecyclerAdapter)
        val snapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(premiumRecyclerAdapter)
        premiumRecyclerAdapter.smoothScrollToPosition(1)
        val layoutManager = premiumRecyclerAdapter.layoutManager
        val snapView = snapHelper.findSnapView(layoutManager)
        val snapOnScrollListener = SnapOnScrollListener(snapHelper, SnapOnScrollListener.Behavior.NOTIFY_ON_SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
        premiumRecyclerAdapter.addOnScrollListener(snapOnScrollListener)
```

Adapter;

```
class ProfilePremiumRecyclerAdapter(
                                    val profilePremiumList: MutableList<ProfilePremium>, val premiumRecyclerView: RecyclerView) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfilePremiumRecyclerAdapter.ModelViewHolder>() {

    class ModelViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val title: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_premium_title)
        val content: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_premium_content)
        val lottieAnim: LottieAnimationView = view.findViewById(R.id.lottie_profile_normal)
        var relative_root_profile_popup: ConstraintLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.relative_root_profile_popup)
        fun bindItems(item: ProfilePremium) {



        }


    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ModelViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_profile_normal, parent, false)

        return ModelViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return profilePremiumList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ModelViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(profilePremiumList.get(position))


    }




}
```

SnapOnScrollListener;

```
class SnapOnScrollListener(
    private val snapHelper: SnapHelper,
    var behavior: Behavior = Behavior.NOTIFY_ON_SCROLL,
    var onSnapPositionChangeListener: OnSnapPositionChangeListener? = null
) : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    var position = 1
    enum class Behavior {
        NOTIFY_ON_SCROLL,
        NOTIFY_ON_SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
    }
    private var snapPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        if (behavior == Behavior.NOTIFY_ON_SCROLL) {
            maybeNotifySnapPositionChange(recyclerView)

        }
    }
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        if (behavior == Behavior.NOTIFY_ON_SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
            && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            maybeNotifySnapPositionChange(recyclerView)
        }
    }
    private fun maybeNotifySnapPositionChange(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        val snapPosition = snapHelper.getSnapPosition(recyclerView)
        val snapPositionChanged = this.snapPosition != snapPosition
        if (snapPositionChanged) {
            onSnapPositionChangeListener?.onSnapPositionChange(snapPosition)
            this.snapPosition = snapPosition
            MyLog.log("recyclerview position: $snapPosition")
            position = snapPosition
            recyclerView.postOnAnimation {
                val itemView       = recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(snapPosition)
                Handler().postDelayed({
                itemView!!.itemView.scaleAnimPremium()
                }, 500)
            }
        }
    }
    fun SnapHelper.getSnapPosition(recyclerView: RecyclerView): Int {
        val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager ?: return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
        val snapView = findSnapView(layoutManager) ?: return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION

        return layoutManager.getPosition(snapView)
    }
}
```

OnSnapPositionChangeListener;

```
interface OnSnapPositionChangeListener {

    fun onSnapPositionChange(position: Int)
}
```

util/Utils.kt scale Anim Premium Function;

```
fun View.scaleAnimPremium() {
    animate().scaleX(1.1f).start()
    animate().scaleY(1.1f).start()
}
```

I'm adding animation to item 1. I want the 1st item to be deleted when I move to 2nd item. So I want to delete the animation of the selected item before.
My animation allows the item to grow / zoom up to 1.1f of the selected item
.currently these codes apply the zoom animation I want to the selected item. But the animations of other items do not come back to their original state.

I tried it but it doesn't work :( ;

```
recyclerView.post {
                val itemView       = recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(snapPosition)
                for (i in 0..3 ) {
                    if (i != snapPosition) {

                        val itemViewOther = recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i)
                        itemViewOther!!.itemView.scaleAnimPremiumClear()

                    }
                }
                Handler().postDelayed({

                itemView!!.itemView.scaleAnimPremium()
                }, 500)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem:
I assign all the selected values into an array and reach the previous selection from the last selection. as follows; In arraylist, I get the length of arraylist 2 missing. The length of anything can be at least 1, so I'm missing 2 (if you don't, you should understand the arraylist's length and sequence concepts well).

```
val arrayList = ArrayList<Int>()

arrayList.add(snapPosition)
            if (arrayList.size > 1){
                val itemViewOther = recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(arrayList[arrayList.size-2])
                itemViewOther!!.itemView.scaleAnimPremiumClear()
                itemViewOther.itemView.updateLayoutParams<RecyclerView.LayoutParams> {
                    marginStart = 20
                }
            }
                val itemView       = recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(snapPosition)

                Handler().postDelayed({

                itemView!!.itemView.scaleAnimPremium()
                }, 500)
```